# How to choose the next @Test method based on the runtime result in TestNG + Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have the first @Test method. The next steps will depend on the result of that first @Test method. Here is the example :

```java
  @Test
    public void checkErrorMessage() {

        if(searching.isErrorExist()==true) {
        //Go to method dealWithErrorPart1();

        }else{
        //Go to method continue1();
        }
    }

  @Test (dependsOnMethods = { "checkErrorMessage" })
  public void  dealWithErrorPart1() {
  //Do something with the Error ... First Step
  }


    @Test (dependsOnMethods = { "dealWithErrorPart1" })
  public void  dealWithErrorPart2() {
  //Do something with the Error ... Second Step
  }

    @Test (dependsOnMethods = { "checkErrorMessage" })
  public void  continue1() {
  //Continue doing something ... Part one
  }

      @Test (dependsOnMethods = { "continue1" })
  public void  continue2() {
  //Continue doing something ... Part two
  }
```

If method `checkErrorMessage()` finds Error Message , then the next method that should be invoked is `dealWithErrorPart1()` . After that `dealWithErrorPart2()` should be run.

If method `checkErrorMessage()` finds **No** Error Message , then the next method that should be invoked is `continue1()` . After that `continue2()` should be run.

So,  `checkErrorMessage()` will decide the next flow of the codes.

Because I can't change the application's behavior, I need to handle each behavior separately. If the application gives me outcome A , then my test automation should execute method A1() , A2() , and A3() .  If the application gives me outcome B , then my test automation should execute method B1() , B2() , and B3() .

How can I achieve that in TestNG? I tried to use `throw new SkipException("Skipping this exception");` but that doesn't seem to solve this case. Thank You.

Comment: This is really not a good idea - the thesis behind unit tests is that each test-case is entirely independent of the others (and thus can be run in any order).  So if you want to test whether e.g. the code handles an error correctly, then have that test-case explicitly create the error condition (rather than relying on other cases).

Comment: Why would you want to choose the next `@Test` method based on a result? Don't you simply have 2 separate cases in your `checkErrorMessage`?  I am no expert with TestNG but couldn't you simply call the case specific methods directly - like any other method?

Comment: Thanks all. Forgot to mention, I actually using TestNG with Selenium Web Driver (Java). So, I am not doing unit testing here, but test automation. The test automation should do `action 1` and then see what is the outcome. The outcome depends on the application's behavior. The test automation will decide what is the next `action` based on that outcome.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, TestNG does not let you build this sort of fluid orchestration of your test methods.

TestNG lets users define order in which test methods will be executed in the ONLY below ways:

- Using `priority` (Here users can define only the order, and the methods will always be executed)
- Using `dependsOnMethods`/`dependsOnGroups` (Here users can define the order and the expectation is that, the method on which the current method is dependent on, will be executed if and only if that method ran to completion without failures)

You might want to just define a TestNG test method and have the test method handle all the application behavior as conditions rather than expect TestNG to control this orchestration for you.